# Cannot install DBD-mysql on windows

Tags: perl, makefile, cpan, dbd-mysql

I'm trying to install this package:
https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql::INSTALL

I have mysql configured on my system.

I'm trying to perform the cmds:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

This is the output of `perl Makefile.PL make

```
E:\umls_perl\DBD-mysql-4.050>perl Makefile.PL


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the
database user '' can connect to your MySQL server
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others.

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to ''@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config) = -IC:\Strawberry\c\bin\..\include\mysql50716
  embedded      (guessed     ) =
  ldflags       (guessed     ) =
  libs          (mysql_config) = -LC:\Strawberry\c\bin\..\lib -lmysql
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
  nossl         (default     ) = 0
  testdb        (default     ) = test
  testhost      (default     ) =
  testpassword  (default     ) =
  testport      (default     ) =
  testsocket    (default     ) =
  testuser      (guessed     ) =

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc DBD::mysql::INSTALL'.

Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Looks good.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/ C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 896.
Using DBI 1.642 (for perl 5.030000 on MSWin32-x64-multi-thread) installed in C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

E:\umls_perl\DBD-mysql-4.050>make
cp lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm blib\lib\Bundle\DBD\mysql.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod blib\lib\DBD\mysql\INSTALL.pod
cp lib/DBD/mysql.pm blib\lib\DBD\mysql.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm blib\lib\DBD\mysql\GetInfo.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for mysql ()
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 "mysql.bs"
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- mysql.bs blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.bs 644
gcc -c  -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -IC:\Strawberry\c\bin\..\include\mysql50716 -DDBD_MYSQL_WITH_SSL -g  -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"4.050\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.050\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   dbdimp.c
In file included from C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI/DBIXS.h:38,
                 from dbdimp.h:20,
                 from dbdimp.c:15:
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI/dbipport.h:4471: warning: "WIDEST_UTYPE" redefined
 #  define WIDEST_UTYPE U64TYPE

In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE/perl.h:2508,
                 from C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI/DBIXS.h:23,
                 from dbdimp.h:20,
                 from dbdimp.c:15:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE/handy.h:1072: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define WIDEST_UTYPE U64

dbdimp.c: In function 'mysql_st_prepare':
dbdimp.c:3207:24: warning: assignment to 'my_bool *' {aka 'char *'} from incompatible pointer type '_Bool *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
           bind->is_null=      (_Bool*) &(fbind->is_null);
                        ^
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/mysql/g" C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI\Driver.xst > mysql.xsi
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap  mysql.xs > mysql.xsc
Warning: duplicate function definition 'do' detected in mysql.xs, line 247
Warning: duplicate function definition 'rows' detected in mysql.xs, line 683
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- mysql.xsc mysql.c
gcc -c  -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -IC:\Strawberry\c\bin\..\include\mysql50716 -DDBD_MYSQL_WITH_SSL -g  -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"4.050\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.050\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   mysql.c
In file included from C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI/DBIXS.h:38,
                 from dbdimp.h:20,
                 from mysql.xs:12:
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI/dbipport.h:4471: warning: "WIDEST_UTYPE" redefined
 #  define WIDEST_UTYPE U64TYPE

In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE/perl.h:2508,
                 from C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI/DBIXS.h:23,
                 from dbdimp.h:20,
                 from mysql.xs:12:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE/handy.h:1072: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define WIDEST_UTYPE U64

gcc -c  -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -IC:\Strawberry\c\bin\..\include\mysql50716 -DDBD_MYSQL_WITH_SSL -g  -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"4.050\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.050\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   socket.c
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"DBD::mysql\", 'DLBASE' => 'mysql', 'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => []);"
g++ mysql.def -o blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.xs.dll -mdll -s -L"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib" dbdimp.o mysql.o socket.o   "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl530.a" "C:\Strawberry\c\bin\..\lib\libmysql.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbccp32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a" -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
make: *** [blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.xs.dll] Error 1
```

I've added mysql to environment variables, tried to attach mysql config when I run the Makefile like this:

```
perl Makefile.PL --mysql_config="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"
```

I've had a similar problem at Linux as well. I don't understand what is the proper way to install this package. Will be glad to get some advice on this subject. Thanks.

Comment: DBD::mysql comes bundled with Strawberry Perl. Why do you need to install it manually?

Comment: It's a prerequisite for another thing I need to install: https://metacpan.org/pod/UMLS::Interface

But thanks for that info, I will check how can I use the Strawberry's Perl DBD::mysql

Comment: You're already using it; otherwise you'd be getting a different error message.